# AOSP. Where is file with list of supported languages?

Tags: android, android-source

I'm trying to find list with supported languages in AOSP (KitKat 4.4)
There is LocalePicker, but from where it reads languages I can't understand.

Comment: Can you explain what do you need? I am not able to understand you.

Comment: Yes, sure. 
I have aosp, where I have only few languages in Settings. But I'm pretty sure, that it supports mach more languages, than I see. So, I want to find config file, where I can add supported languages to AOSP

Comment: You mean Settings -- Languages & Input --> Languages --> Add a language?

Comment: Every version of android based os can have different enumeration of languages.  For example, MIUI has only English and two Chinese variants.

Comment: I understand that every version of Android has different set of languages. My questions is from where Settings app read list of available languages

Comment: https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/cm-11.0/core/java/com/android/internal/app/LocalePicker.java#L126-L127

https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/cm-11.0/core/res/res/values/arrays.xml#L337-L347

Comment: Try adding locale in that array and give it a try.

Comment: I've seen it too, but there is no list of all languages, which supports my aosp

Comment: Check java.util.Locale

Answer (score 4):

I found solution
Supported locales is configured in aosp/device/your_vendor/your_mk_file.mk

```
# For all locales, $(call inherit-product, build/target/product/languages_full.mk)
PRODUCT_LOCALES := en_US es_US de_DE zh_TW fr_FR it_IT sv_SE nb_NO
```

Comment: error: cannot assign to readonly variable: PRODUCT_LOCALES... any idea?